# Problem with PHP wordpress, Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\epoch\classes\core.php on line 190

Tags: plugins, php

I was using Epoch plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/epoch/) in my wordpress template for comments section. it was working file but all of a sudden the comments stopped to load and this error stars showing

> Notice: Undefined index: options in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\epoch\classes\core.php on line 190

this is the code in line 190 `if( 'iframe' != $options['options']['theme'] ) {
            return $template;
        }`

can anyone suggest me what to do?

Comment: As the error message is telling you, there is just no entry `options` in that variable. We cannot tell you why that is, because it depends on code that is not part of your question. Please ask the plugin author.